# Is it possible to convert ObjectSet to DbSet in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: entity-framework, dbset, objectset

I am working on upgrading a WPF application from using .Net4/EF 4.4 to .Net4.5/EF 6.1.  After the upgrade I will use DbContext (since there was no POCO-generator for ObjectContext).

The application use a Repository/UnitOfWork-pattern to access Entity Framework, and before the upgrade I could set the ObjectSet.MergeOption to OverwriteChanges (in the repository-class), but the DbSet-class does not have this feature. However, I know that I can get to a ObjectSet from the DbContext by using the IObjectContextAdapter. (See code below). But it seems that setting the MergeOption on the created ObjectSet will not reflect back to the DbSet.

So my question is this: is there any way to convert the ObjectSet back to a DbSet (conserving the MergeOption-setting)?

This is some of the repository class:

```
public class SqlRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    protected DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public SqlRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        var set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        set.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;


        dbSet = context.Set<T>();
//I would like to do something like this: dbSet = (DbSet)set;


    }
}
```

Comment: There is a POCO generator: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/66612113-549c-4a9e-a14a-f629ceb3f89a

Comment: @ErikEJ Yes, I am aware of that, but I don't think it creates POCOs, rather EntityObject derived classes? When I used it, it only created the xxModel.tt-file, not the xxModel.Context.tt-file as it would do in the EF 4.4-version of the T4.

Comment: Sorry, you are right...

Comment: Its a bit of a joke really, they broke all the MergeOption functionality without even considering the implications on real world applications

Comment: @TomDeloford Yeah, and I have really struggled to find another way to do this. I would think that many other would need the Overwrite Changes option.

Comment: See my answer below, it might help you

Comment: For the life of me I can't figure out what you are trying to do that can't be accomplished through the many methods available for restoring original values to individual entities through reload, apply current values etc or by simply setting the objects properties to unchanged if you're just trying to prevent them from being saved. Then there's attach/detach, execute store, refresh on object context and dbsql that returns typed result sets. I know you've got to have a good reason for your question, I'd just like to know what problem you're trying to solve. ;-)

Comment: @DeShanBaptiste Hi and thank you for commenting. It has been a while since I looked at that problem now, and I am a bit busy at the moment. I will try to find the time to explain more, just not right now :)  (In short: if I have a collection of object in memory that I refresh with data from DB, then I want the values from the DB to overwrite the data in memory if there are any changes...like the MergeOption.OverWriteChanges does in the ObjectSet.)

Answer (score 0):

Although not a direct answer to your question, I have come up with a T4 based solution to the EF oversight around MergeOption not being accessible in DbSet. It seems from your question this is what you are looking for?

In the default Context you have something generated by the T4 generator like:

```
public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

*etc.*

My approach is to edit the T4 to add Getters for each Entity that provide direct access the ObjectSet as an IQueryable:

```
public IQueryable<Person> GetPersons(MergeOption mergeOption = MergeOption.AppendOnly, bool useQueryImplentation = true) 
{ 
    return useQueryImplementation ? GetSet<Person>(mergeOption).QueryImplementation() : GetSet<Person>(mergeOption); 
}
```

Then in a base DataContext

```
public class DataContextBase
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the forced MergeOption. When this is set all queries 
    /// generated using GetObjectSet will use this value
    /// </summary>
    public MergeOption? MergeOption { get; set; }


/// <summary>
/// Gets an ObjectSet of type T optionally providing a MergeOption.
/// <remarks>Warning: if a DataContext.MergeOption is specified it will take precedence over the passed value</remarks>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TEntity">ObjectSet entity Type</typeparam>
/// <param name="mergeOption">The MergeOption for the query (overriden by DataContext.MergeOption)</param>
protected IQueryable<TEntity> GetObjectSet<TEntity>(MergeOption? mergeOption = null) where TEntity : class
{
    var set = Context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
    set.MergeOption = MergeOption ?? mergeOption ?? MergeOption.AppendOnly;

    return set;
}
```

By creating a default Extension method for an IQueryable as below you can optionally add your own implenations of QueryImplementation for each table/type so that all users of your table get sorting or includes etc. (this part is not required to answer the question but its useful anyway)

So for example you could add the following to always Include Addresses when calling GetPersons()

```
 public static class CustomQueryImplentations
 {
        public static IQueryable<Person> QueryImplementation(this IQueryable<Person> source)
        {
            return source
                .Include(r => r.Addresses)
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.Name);
        }
  }
```

Finally:

```
//just load a simple list with no tracking (Fast!)
var people = Database.GetPersons(MergeOption.NoTracking);

//user wants to edit Person so now need Attached Tracked Person (Slow)
var peson = Database.GetPersons(MergeOption.OverwriteChanges).FirstOrDefault(p => p.PersonID = 1);

//user makes changes and on another machine sometime later user clicks refresh
var people = Database.GetPersons(MergeOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

Or you can (as I have) write something like

```
Database.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
```

*refresh loads of entities using existing Get methods but will now ALL overwrite Attached entities*

```
Database.MergeOption = null;
```

Something to note is that if you load AsNoTracking before you make changes you need to either Re-Attach or probably better reload with OverwriteChanges to ensure you have the latest Entity.

Comment: Thank you for Your example. I will have a look at it more closely when I get the time... I have had to move on to other Things since my post. I remember that one of the difficult Things for me was that the Application I was trying to Upgrade used a very generic approach for the EF Things (Repository/Uow) and that made it difficult to take advantage of some of the more specific features of EF. But again, thanks for the suggestion.